# How to avoid deploying endpoints in dependent projects net core 6?

Tags: security, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, endpoint

I have two projects **baseApi** and **myOtherApi** , both legacy projects are in net6.0

**baseApi** is a basic API deployed as *http://myBasicApi.com* and it have some endpoints:

> "/groups/opened"
> "/users/whitelist"

**myOtherApi** is a complementary API deployed as http://myOtherApi.com and it have other endpoints:

> "/trucks/available"
> "/invoices/{groupId}"

**myOtherApi** depends of **baseApi** (because it share its models classes), it's Ok.

But the issue is when I deploy **myOtherApi** it deploys endpoints of **baseApi** (i.e. http://myOtherApi.com/users/whitelist responses OK), and it's wrong because **baseApi** endpoints shuoldn't be exposed in this project (baseApi is only for admin clients)

Are there some config or another way to avoid expose these external endpoints on http://myOtherApi.com?

Comment: Hi @yecid, where did you host the application?

Comment: Hi @Rena , it's hosted in Azure

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the issue previously. You can check details in this thread: Calling [Another Project's Controller From A Project In The Same Solution (.NET Core )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72224545/7687666)

**Conclusion:**

There is no way of restricting this.

WHY

1. Any assembly can use any public type of other assemblies.
2. (**Controller**) Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protect, protected internal or private protected.

## Suggestion

1. In your baseApi  and myOtherApi project, you should have some layers, sth like:

   ```
   baseApi -- mvc or api  
   baseApi.BLL
   baseApi.DAL  
   baseApi.Model  
   baseApi.Service
   baseApi.IService  
   baseApi. ...

   myOtherApi-- mvc or api  
   myOtherApi.BLL
   myOtherApi.DAL  
   baseApi.Model  
   myOtherApi.Service
   myOtherApi.IService  
   myOtherApi. ...
   ```
2. Pls check the structure of the project, and in your another project, if you want add Model layer to the new project, you can add this class library project directly. You don't need add the whole project as reference to the new project.