# Routes from seperate project are not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my Main project which is the start up project and inside a view with an anchor

```
<a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="IndexJson" />
```

The controller Products exists in a separate project. So if I clicked on the anchor the URL goes to "HTTP://localhost:80/Products/IndexJson" but shows nothing error 404. How can I set the correct routing in order to make it work?
My controller code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexJson()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Another Project's Controller From A Project In The Same Solution (.NET Core )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216567/calling-another-projects-controller-from-a-project-in-the-same-solution-net-c)

Comment: Unless `Main` references `Products` it will have no way to know about those routes. `Products` looks like an independent web app though, so it can't be referenced. Are you trying to generate a URL pointing to that other web site? Where does that site run ? Port 80? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The `<a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="IndexJson" />` will render the a tag helper like this `<a href="/Products/IndexJson"></a>`.  When you click the herf link, it will redirect to current domain's product/indexjson url not the product's website's product/indexjson.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could modify the a tag with the product application's url instead of using the a tag helper generated url.

Like below:

```
<a href="https://domian.com/Products/IndexJson">
```